# A template that contains std collection iterators

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++14, template-templates

This template is able to store vector iterator(s) of a specific type.

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
  typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator it;

  std::vector<it> m_collection;
};
```

How can template be made more generic and support other std collection iterators (`std::list`, `std::deque` etc)?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? This sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can template be made more generic and support other std collection iterators (list, deque etc)?

Do you want to pass the containers as template arguments?

That is: are you looking for template-template arguments?

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T>
struct foo
{
  typedef typename C<T>::iterator it;

  std::vector<it> m_collection;
};
```

Usable as follows

```
foo<std::vector, int>  fvi;
foo<std::set, long>    fsl;
```

Or maybe

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct foo
{
  typedef typename C<Ts...>::iterator it;

  std::vector<it> m_collection;
};
```

So you can use it also for maps ?

```
foo<std::map, int, std::string>      fmis;
foo<std::unordered_map, long, char>  fulc;
```

Unfortunately this solution is incompatible with `std::array`, that require a not-template argument.

Or maybe you want to pass the type and select container and contained type as through specialization?

```
template <typename>
struct foo;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct foo<C<Ts...>>
{
  typedef typename C<Ts...>::iterator it;

  std::vector<it> m_collection;
};
```

So you can use it as follows

```
foo<std::vector<int>>                fvi;
foo<std::set<long>>                  fsl;
foo<std::map<int, std::string>>      fmis;
foo<std::unordered_map<long, char>>  fulc;
```

and also add a specialization for `std::array`

```
template <template <typename, std::size_t> class A,
          typename T, std::size_t N>
struct foo<A<T, N>>
{
  typedef typename A<T, N>::iterator it;

  std::vector<it> m_collection;
};
```

Or, maybe, simply

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
  typedef typename T::iterator it;

  std::vector<it> m_collection;
};
```

without deducing container and contained type?

Comment: Very good answer. Your first suggestion looks perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal running example where `foo` can switch between sequence containers to store `it`:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <deque> 
#include <list> 

template
<
    typename T, 
    template<typename, typename> class SequenceContainer,
    template <typename> class Allocator = std::allocator
>
struct foo
{
    typedef typename SequenceContainer<T, Allocator<T>>::iterator it;

    SequenceContainer<it, Allocator<it>> m_collection;
};

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    foo<double, vector> vecFoo; 
    foo<double, deque>  dequeFoo; 
    foo<double, list>   listFoo; 

    return 0;
};
```